# Ramda methods returning 'undefined' when testing with Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, jestjs, ramda.js

I am trying to test some code that uses [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/). I'm using Jasmine and Jest.

All the Ramda methods I have attempted to use only return 'undefined', according to Jest.

Here's a simplified version of the code (I have confirmed that this simplified version fails):

```
 let R = require('ramda')

 let arr = [0, 1, 2]
 let newArr = R.adjust(R.add(10), 1, arr)

 describe('adjust', function() {

   it('should apply the function only to the second element in the array', () => {
     expect(newArr).toBe([0, 11, 2]);
   })

 })
```

This is the error message I receive when running the tests:

```
 FAIL  tests/functional-programming/ramda/lists/adjust.test.js (0.855s)
 ● adjust › it should apply the function only to the second element in the array
 - Expected: undefined toBe: {
   | 0: 0,
   | 1: 11,
   | 2: 2
 }
    at Spec.<anonymous> (tests/functional-programming/ramda/lists/adjust.test.js:12:20)

 1 test failed, 51 tests passed (52 total in 15 test suites, run time 3.07s)
```

I'm not sure what is wrong with the above code. Why does newArr have a value of undefined?

Answer (score 1):

Do you somehow run jasmine with harmony flag?

In any way, if you avoid using `let` and `() =>`, then it works like a charm:

```
var R = require('ramda');
var arr = [0,1,2];
var newArr = R.adjust(R.add(10), 1, arr);

describe("adjust", function() {
  it("should apply the function only to the second element", function() {
    // replaced toBe with toEqual matcher
    expect(newArr).toEqual([0,11,2]);
  });
});
```

Comment: Simply avoiding ES6/ES2015 isn't really a solution – I'm trying to figure out _why_ there are issues of scope in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Does this just have to do with the scope of your `let` statement?

The Ramda code certainly works: http://bit.ly/1jN5fkb

Does it work if you rearrange like this?:

```
let R = require('ramda')

describe('adjust', function() {
   let arr = [0, 1, 2]
   let newArr = R.adjust(R.add(10), 1, arr)

   it('should apply the function only to the second element in the array', () => {
       expect(newArr).toBe([0, 11, 2]);
   })
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `expected(newArr)` still returns `undefined`, I even tried pasting in your code block and ran the test suite.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the order of operation? Or does the fact that Ramda uses currying heavily in the library have anything to do with `R.adjust()` returning `undefined`?